# Take results within two dates

Tags: php, jquery, date, mysqli

I have tried various solutions here on the site but unfortunately I did not succeed. I would need that this query that already takes the results with the highest value of the field "vote_up", could also take a second additional value. It picks up the results within a given date (posted_date), a start date and a finish date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   stories S 
       LEFT JOIN categories C 
              ON C.category_id = S.c_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT voted_story, 
                         voter_ip 
                  FROM   votes 
                  WHERE  voter_ip = '$ip_address' 
                  GROUP  BY voted_story) V 
              ON V.voted_story = S.story_id 
WHERE  S.story_active = 1 
ORDER  BY S.vote_up DESC 
LIMIT  0, 16
```

**Adding just for clarification, my difficulty is the syntax that makes me errors especially I do not know how to insert two "where" in the same query.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional `WHERE` condition clauses for checking posted date as-well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   stories S 
   LEFT JOIN categories C 
          ON C.category_id = S.c_id 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT voted_story, voter_ip 
              FROM   votes 
              WHERE  voter_ip = "$ip_address" 
              GROUP  BY voted_story) V 
          ON V.voted_story = S.story_id 
WHERE
    S.story_active = 1 AND
    S.posted_date > "$startDate" AND
    S.posted_date < "$endDate"
ORDER  BY S.vote_up DESC 
LIMIT  0, 16
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ip_address' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'